# compare numbers in C

Tags: c, compare

```
printf("Insert money for payment: ");

while( !(scanf("%g\n", &insertMoney) == EOF || !insertMoney) ){

    if(insertMoney == 0.05f ||insertMoney == 100 || insertMoney == 50 || insertMoney == 20 || insertMoney == 10 || insertMoney == 5 || insertMoney == 2 || insertMoney == 1 || insertMoney == 0.50 || insertMoney == 0.2 || insertMoney == 0.20 || insertMoney == 0.1 || insertMoney == 0.02 || insertMoney == 0.01 || insertMoney == 0 )           
        totalSum += insertMoney;
    else{
        fake = insertMoney;
        printf("%g is invalid!\n", fake);
        return 1;       
        }   
     }
```

If i insert 100, 50 or any number from if, works normaly.
**If i insert 0.20 or 0.05 (any number with 0.xx) say me is invalid.**

PS: insertMoney is float.

Comment: This question [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Read documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and of every function you are using. Read also http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Hmm, `scanf("%g\n", &insertMoney) == EOF` ??? The return value of scanf here can only be 0 or 1. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Sorry guys, but still understand :(

Comment: Another link: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Please note that `0.1` is not *exactly representable* in floating point format. So if you multiply that by `10` it *does not equal `1.0`*.

Comment: I understand where is the problem, but how can resolve it? 

Thanks

Comment: By using integer types: work in cents.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: I don't see why `scanf()` can't return EOF in contex, though I agree that it could return 0 or 1 too, and the program should only continue when the return value is 1.  The `if (!(condition_1 || !condition_2))` notation is decidedly more complex than it should be, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int fequal(float a, float b)
{
    float epsilon = 0.000000001;

    if (fabs(a - b) < epsilon)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}


fequal(0.5, insertMoney)
```

this is the answer :)